# data binding to list size is not working?

Tags: android, data-binding

I have an android app that shows a screen to the user to enter data if a List is empty, otherwise it shows the List in a recyclerview.

When the app first starts this works fine. The data must be read from an online database so the empty list text shows until the data is loaded and then the list shows. If I delete the entries from the database using the app the List size goes to zero, but the empty list does not show, the Recyclerview remains visible (but empty sine the List is empty.

The binding for the empty textview is:

```
android:visibility="@{list.size() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

and for the recyclerview is:

```
android:visibility="@{list.size() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

The List is bound using:

```
binding.setList(mList) ;
```

As I said the startup of the app works so I don't understand why having the list go to empty does not also work.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you invoke `binding.setList(mList)` every time after your list was changed?

Comment: Since you are not using a Observable object in xml `android:visibility="@{list.size() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"`, you need to call `binding.setList(mList) ;` every time your list is updated (When you first get from server and also when you delete an item).

Comment: Yes I am calling binding.setList(mList) when the list is updated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not triggering the "binding update" after deleting items from database. Anyway you could approach it differently, using let's say `LiveData<Boolean>` or `ObservableBoolean` that would say wheter list is empty or not, your binding expression would not change.

The advantage of using `LiveData` or `Observable<T>`with dataBinding is that everytime you change the value of these it is "propagated" to the view automatically - so you dont need to do this `binding.setList(mList);` each time view should update. There is also `ObservableArrayList`, binding that instead of regular `List` might work too, but I haven't tried that.

[see using observables with databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability)

By the way the `LiveData` + databinding works even better if you place your `LiveData` into a `ViewModel` and bind from xml to that.

Comment: Thank you, however I do not want to change my app to use LiveData at this time.

Comment: it makes life alot easier